# In a sbt project, how to get full list of dependencies with scope?

Tags: sbt

In a sbt project, how to get full list of dependencies(including transitive dependencies) with scope?

For Example:

```
xxx.jar(Compile)
yyy.jar(Provided)
zzz.jar(Test)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `sbt` shell you can execute one or all of the following commands:

```
    Test / fullClasspath
    Runtime / fullClasspath
    Compile / fullClasspath
```

Which will output the jars associated with the scope (Test/Runtime/Compile).

If you want to get a bit more fancy, `sbt` provides a number of ways of interacting with the outputs generated through the dependency management system. The documentation is [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Update-Report.html).

For example, you could add this to your `build.sbt` file:

```
lazy val printReport = taskKey[Unit]("Report which jars are in each scope.")
printReport := {
  val updateReport: UpdateReport = update.value
  val jarFilter: ArtifactFilter = artifactFilter(`type` = "jar")
  val testFilter = configurationFilter(name = "test")
  val compileFilter = configurationFilter(name = "compile")

  val testJars = updateReport.matching(jarFilter && testFilter)
  val compileJars = updateReport.matching(jarFilter && compileFilter)

  println("Test jars:\n===")
  for (jar <- testJars.sorted) yield {println(jar.getName)}

  println("\n\n******\n\n")

  println("compile jars:\n===")
  for (jar <- compileJars.sorted) yield {println(jar.getName)}
}
```

It creates a new task `printReport` which can be executed like a normal `sbt` command with `sbt printReport`. It takes the value of the `UpdateReport` which is generated by the `update` task, and then filters for jar files in the respective test/compile scopes before printing the results.